# where does python interpreter fit in Tensorflow runtime architecture?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cpython

According to [Tensorflow architecture page](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/architecture), the following figure illustrates the general architecture of Tensorflow runtime architecture. A C API separates user level code in different languages from the core runtime.

How does python interpreter fit in the picture? In parallel to Tensorflow runtime?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the parts above the C API are implemented in Python. You run those parts using a Python interpreter.

More verbosely, the C API and below, is basically just a library. You can use this library from different languages. For training, you usually use Python (all tf.* APIs), which runs using Python interpreter. For inference, you usually use Java or C++. In this case, no Python interpreter is necessary.